# NSException callStackSymbols

Tags: objective-c, nsexception

When exception occurred there is stack trace this kind:

> 2   CoreFoundation   0x013bd1cc -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 236
>   3   –ò–°–≠–î         0x0000ac76 -[ContentButton handleGesture:] + 326
>   4   UIKit            0x00de24f2 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 730
>       ...

I see that exception occurred when I try to get `objectAtIndex:` in NSArray in my custom class `ContentButton` in `handleGesture:` method.

But what does this numbers after message mean (like +236)?

In java stack trace that mean line number where exception occurred (as I know). but message `[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]` sent in line 47 (not 236).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: +236 means the offset in bytes from the beginning of the method in the binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great video from WWDC 2010 on understanding crash reports.

[You can find it here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=317) (login to Apple Developer required)

Comment: Still don't know what does this numbers means. In video was told that XCode symbolises any crash reports by self, but is not - still get +236-like appends to messages name and still don't know what is this..

Comment: @GusevAndrey I'm confused, too. As far as I can tell, it's the number of line numbers down from the declaration of the method _in the assembly code_. Not terribly helpful unless you know precisely how every line of your class translates to Assembly, and how the compiler associated variables.